# Woocommerce API not working with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I wrote a piece of javascript to connect to my woocommerce API and display orders. It was working fine until the other day and now I have no idea why it wont work. It returns -

> {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}

I have checked the API keys, created new ones etc, made sure it's enabled etc... Below is the code and any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

To add to the clues, I have two installations of wordpress on this host, on my other install this code works perfectly fine. I have made sure to mimic the htaccess file but didn't fix the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://alphasarms.com.au/wp-json/wc/v2/orders',
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'Basic ' + btoa('ck_8537d438d9ca9eb022481b7835c3c0439249b979:cs_3e101a1175b589f26ac26f7fd7d4e758cca3cb1d'),
       // 'status':'completed',
       // 'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'status':'processing','per_page':'99'},
    success: function(data){

    console.log(data);


    }
  });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `'Content-Type':'application/json'` in headers? Not sure but it could be the issue or probably related to Authentication

Comment: Thanks but doesnt help.